# Fancybox on a fancy box

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to figure out a way where I click an image and a fancy box appears with 3 buttons and when I click on any of the buttons, i get a gallery using fancy box.
Is that possible?
I want an Fancy box 1:iFrame-->Fancybox 2: One Image gallery

I read somewhere it is, and the others said its not, everyone is giving different can anyone help?

Comment: user `thickbox` for `iframe` and `fancybox` for `gallery`

http://thickbox.net/

http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fancybox v2.x, it's as easy as binding fancybox to your box with buttons and your image galleries so, to launch the fancybox with buttons, create a html like

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#buttonsContainer"><img src="images/01t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

.....**notice** that we are targeting an `inline` content with `id="buttonsContainer"`. Then the *hidden* html content can be like

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <div id="buttonsContainer">
  <a class="fancybox myButton" href="images/01.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery01" title="gallery 01">open gallery 01</a>
  <a class="fancybox myButton" href="images/02.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery02" title="gallery 02">open gallery 02</a>
  <a class="fancybox myButton" href="images/03.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery03" title="gallery 03">open gallery 03</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a class="fancybox" href="images/04.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery01" title="gallery 01"></a>
  <a class="fancybox" href="images/05.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery02" title="gallery 02"></a>
  <a class="fancybox" href="images/06.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery03" title="gallery 03"></a>
  <a class="fancybox" href="images/07.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery01" title="gallery 01"></a>
  <a class="fancybox" href="images/08.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery03" title="gallery 03"></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Notice** that we have set to sections, one for the buttons (`buttonsContainer`) and one for the galleries.

The custom fancybox script can be as simple as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fancybox").fancybox();
}); // ready
```

...which will work for both, the box with buttons and the image galleries.

see [WORKING DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/openGalleriesFromfancybox_21oct12.html)